# open apn activity on Lollipop

Tags: android

I am trying to open an APN activity when user touch a button, but this code do not work in Lollipop, can anyone help me, please? Thank you.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.ApnSettings");
  startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this ..

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS)
```

or

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS, 0));
```

Hope it works